# What brands make propane lanterns, stoves, heaters, and accessories in America?

Tags: camping, cooking

The accessories I'm looking for are things like propane trees and hoses, and obviously stoves, heaters, and lanterns are self explanatory. Nobody seems to talk about where things are made anymore, and in my experience that means they're NOT made in the US.

I'm going camping in three weeks and need a new lantern, and a new tree. The stove and heater perhaps this winter.

Are there any brands that still make these camping items here in the US?

Comment: Many companies that manufacture goods in one country also manufacture them in others. Second, many goods assembled in one country depend on parts imported from others; quite a lot of an "American-made" car or motorcycle regardless of make depends on parts made in Mexico, Canada, Europe, or Asia. Third, purchasing an item based on its place of manufacture instead of its quality and value strikes me as quite odd. It would be subsidizing uncompetitiveness in other areas, which does neither the worker nor the company good in the long run.

Comment: @choster It's actually a rather common sentiment, and is often based on perceived quality (and keeping primary jobs at home). Many companies do, however, here in the USA, because of that sentiment, many are no longer manufacturing in other countries so then can advertize that all their goods are USA made. Products with a few dozen or hundred parts are manufactured very differently (parts purchase wise) than ones with a few thousand or more (stove vs car). For the company it is a competitive strategy that currently works in the USA.

Answer (score 5):

I think what you are looking for is [Century Camping](http://www.centurycamping.com/) gear. It is mostly made in USA and they have all the accessories that you are looking for. If something they sell is made elsewhere, they note the country of origin in the product specs.

Coleman still makes some stuff here but most of it is in China now. You have to check the individual box for them.

You might also want to try REI.com. They are a great camping site and their online store has a button to show only made in USA items. I tested this and found it odd that they flagged all Century Camping gear as imported when only 1 of their stoves is actually imported.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize REI had that option.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.madeinusa.org/nav.cgi?data/camp allows you to search for camping items made in the US.

Comment: If you look at the dates on most of the posts they are from 3-5 years ago. Many (not all) of the listed companies have moved some production offshore in recent years. Good answer, just needs a qualifier.

Comment: Very good point.  Lists like that are only useful if they are kept up to date.